# Both if and else condition are executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an if condition which will change the state value, and the else part assigns a different value to the state. but both are being executed. how to avoid that.

```
getJobId = (event) => {
    const { appliedjobs } = this.props
    {appliedjobs && appliedjobs.map(job => {
        if(event.target.getAttribute('name')===job.id)
        {
            this.setState({applystatus:job.applystatus},()=>{
            console.log('====================================');
            console.log(this.state.applystatus);
            console.log('====================================');
            })
        }
        else if(event.target.getAttribute('name')!=job.id){     
            this.setState({applystatus:"apply now"},()=>{
            console.log('====================================');
            console.log("else ",this.state.applystatus);
            console.log('====================================');
            })
        }
      })}
      this.setState({
      jobid: event.target.getAttribute('name')
     }, () => this.sendJobId())
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure your function is executed only once?

Comment: You're using : `appliedjobs.map` so your code passing on each appliedJob but I imagine that only one is corresponding to your event

Comment: this event is executed when i click a particular task, which grabs the attribute name and checks it with the job id.

Comment: "checks it with the job id" => in fact with all your job ids in your `this.props.appliedjobs` array. `map` is looping over it. For example : if you have 2 `job`s into `this.props.appliedjobs` and your `event.name` == 1, it will match with the first job (pass into IF), and then, not match with the second job item (pass into ELSE). I can answer to be clearer if you want.

Comment: Does this `applideJobs` array contains more than one element? In that case it will execute the correct condition for the expected `jobId` and the other clause for the ones you are not looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping over your `applidjobs` array, and you set `state.applystatus` in both branches of your `if` statement during each iteration. So the `applystatus` value will be the one set during the last iteration:

```
appliedjobs.map(job => {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('name') === job.id) {
    this.setState({ applystatus: job.applystatus })
  } else if (event.target.getAttribute('name') != job.id) {     
    this.setState({ applystatus: 'apply now' })
  }
})
this.setState({ jobid: event.target.getAttribute('name') }, () => this.sendJobId())
```

I suggest to look for the job matching the `name` attribute, if found, set the `applystatus` to the job's status, else set it to `apply now`, you don't need to map or use an `if/else` statement:

```
const jobid = event.target.getAttribute('name');
const job = appliedjobs.find(({ id }) => id === jobid );
this.setState({
  applystatus: job ? job.applystatus : 'apply now,
  jobid
}, () => this.sendJobId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `else if` statement might return the same, as `!=` can return a false positive. You just need an else statement though:

```
            if(event.target.getAttribute('name')===job.id) { ... }
            else { ... }
```

This should in any way only execute the `setState` function within the else block if the `if` statement is definitely false.

Comment: i tried that, but it was executing the else part as well... only then i tried elseif

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code, you should be doing something like this:

```
getJobId = (event) => {
  const { appliedjobs } = this.props
  const jobid = event.target.getAttribute('name')
  const job = appliedjobs.find( j => j.id == jobid)
  const applystatus = job ? job.applystatus : "apply now"

  this.setState({ applystatus, jobid })
}
```

Finding the job per its id and setting on state its status, is that correct?